# Serializing an object into the body of a WCF request using webHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, serialization

I have a WCF service exposed with a webHttpBinding endpoint.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
    UriTemplate = "/?action=DoSomething&v1={value1}&v2={value2}")]
void DoSomething(string value1, string value2, MySimpleObject value3);
```

In theory, if I call this, the first two parameters (value1 & value 2) are taken from the Uri and the final one (value3) should be deserialized from the body of the request.

Assuming I am using Json as the RequestFormat, what is the best way of serialising an instance of MySimpleObject into the body of the request before I send it ? This, for instance, does not seem to work :

```
HttpWebRequest sendRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
sendRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
sendRequest.Method = "POST";
using (var sendRequestStream = sendRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = 
        new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MySimpleObject));
    jsonSerializer.WriteObject(sendRequestStream, obj);
    sendRequestStream.Close();
}
sendRequest.GetResponse().Close();
```

Comment: I removed references to REST from this question because it is just confusing the issue.  If you were doing something RESTful then this question would be irrelevant.

Comment: Suggestion: try it with that last parameter being an int and get that working first.

Comment: John Saunders : I already did that. It works fine without the object parameter and with the object replaced with an int.

Comment: @Bert: I recommend you edit your question to add the information that you've tried int.

Comment: @Bert: please also update to say what you mean by "doesn't seem to work".

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd do differently is to put the WebResponse into a `using` block:

```
using (var response = sendRequest.GetResponse())
{
}
```

I'd be concerned about what happens if the `Close` throws an exception in your code.

Also, are you logging exceptions? You might want to try:

```
try
{
    using (var response = sendRequest.GetResponse())
    {
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); // Or however you want to display it
    throw;
}
```

This will ensure that you know of any problems with the response (like a non-200 HTTP status).

Comment: There are no exceptions. The response code from the endpoint is 202 Accepted. I've been looking at the service trace logs and there were some mismatch errors in some cases and deserialization errors in others. I now have this working using both Json serialization (via both the DataContractJsonSerializedr and Json.Net) and using the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

I now have this working using both Json serialization (via both the DataContractJsonSerializer and Json.Net) and using the XmlSerializer.

The odd thing is that the RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml property in the web invoke attribute seems to be ignored, i.e. inbound messages seem to be deserialized from xml or json regardless of this setting.